# Tkinter: Send variable to function in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have something like this

```
   for r, serviceItem in enumerate(service):
        label.append('')
        label[r]= tk.Button(self, text="?",command=lambda:mensaje(r))
        label[r].config(font=("Verdana",14))
        label[r].grid(row=r,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
```

What I want to do is create a menu in tkinter inside a for loop and pass the value of a variable at that point in the loop to a function.

In the example I show, when pressing the button the message function always receives the value of r in the last round, I needed the value of that variable to arrive at the moment I created the label.

Comment: Similar question has been asked several times.  You need to use default value to argument of lambda function to bind the value when the lambda created: `lambda r=r: mensaje(r)`

Comment: thank you very much i finally got it with `command = partial (message, r)`
Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1):

command = partial (message, r) o r lambda r=r: mensaje(r) worked perfectly.
solved!